What sicha/mammer or any published work by the Rebbe say that Moses wanted us to reach a complete level of prophecy instead of a medium of Sefer Torah
BH
Hi, correct me if I’m wrong that in Numbers 11:29 Moses says that he wishes that all us would be prophets. My main question is regarding prophecy and the revelation at Mount Sinai.
I heard on one Rav's video online one time - don't remember the source - although he was saying that it says from a Chabad source I believe that Moses wanted us to become prophets and have complete connection with Hashem without no written medium although instead of this direct connection we asked for the Torah to be written down so he went up to Mount Sinai wrote down the Torah and brought it down.
So if this true what source does it say this in?

Can you link the video?

I saw something related to the title today (but not the full idea). It's likely when I find it, it will have references to any sources related to it BH. I'll try to have a look soon. It's likely a sicha for Ki Tavo, because I did learn a couple of those today

@RabbiKaii lemme know when you can it would be awesome to know

@RabbiKaii Also what Volume in Ki Tavo?

@David sorry, I couldn't find it (I think, actually, that what I was remembering is from Tomer Devora 2 which briefly discusses it, which I was learning a couple of days ago, so not from Chassidus - I wish I had a better memory!). It is related to the pasuk Vayikra 11:29. If you start there, you might be able to find it. If I find it again, I will bli neder return and post it. Hatzlacha
